# Is it possible to proxy\tunnle TCP through Apache HTTP web server?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, apache2

A customer uses Apache HTTP Webserver (**AW**) to redirect HTTP requests to Apache Tomcat (**AT**).

I need to add a special servlet to a current application being served by **AT**. This servlet will just start a thread and do nothing more. This thread's sole purpose is to listen to incoming TCP connections.

Is it possible to redirect inbound TCP connections received by **AW**, to **AT** ?

So **AW** will only act as a TCP proxy.<s>I prefer a proxy solution, tunneling is not preferable but I would consider it if there is no other solution.</s>

I have no control over the client, which expects me to follow a strict custom text-based protocol.

[Incoming connection]

```
Client -> AW -> AT
```

[Response]

```
Client <- AW <- AT
```

Comment: A [web socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) connection can be (reverse) proxied by apache with mod_proxy_wstunnel

Comment: @HBruijn, does this mandate a specific protocol over TCP ? Such as the websocket protocol ?

Comment: Yes, but it allows you the  most flexibility if your want to interact with a webserver

Comment: @HBruijn, thanks. But I have no control over the client. I'm afraid this won't work. Thanks again.

Comment: This would be cool to have. Pure TCP socket tunnel in any ws